# YouTube Data API: add a subscription

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm using YouTube's V3 Data API to add a subscription to a channel. This occurs on a Wordpress installation.

I added Google APIs (for oauth) on Wordpress theme functions:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'googleapi', 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady', array(), '1.0.0', true );
```

I added in the same way the oauth javascript file, which is the first one here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript.

Following this guide(https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert (Apps Script)), I extended the OAuth js with the addSubscription method.

Google Client API seems to be loaded and working as it calls correctly googleApiClientReady on the oauth javascript.

So, this is how the subscription is being inserted:

OAUTH JAVASCRIPT

```
... ... ...

// After the API loads
function handleAPILoaded() {
  addSubscription();
}
function addSubscription() {
  // Replace this channel ID with the channel ID you want to subscribe to
  var channelId = 'this is filled with the channel ID';
  var resource = {
    snippet: {
      resourceId: {
        kind: 'youtube#channel',
        channelId: channelId
      }
    }
  };

  try {
    var response = YouTube.Subscriptions.insert(resource, 'snippet');
    jQuery('#success').show();

  } catch (e) {
    if(e.message.match('subscriptionDuplicate')) {
      jQuery('#success').show();
    } else {
      jQuery('#fail').show();

      alert("Please send us a mail () with the following: ERROR: " + e.message);
    }

  }
```

So, the first error comes with

```
YouTube.Subscriptions.insert(resource, 'snippet')
```

It says YouTube is not defined. I replaced it with:

```
gapi.client.youtube.subscriptions.insert(resource, 'snippet');
```

And that error went away. When checking response, as the subscription isn't completed, this is what I get

```
{"wc":1,"hg":{"Ph":null,"hg":{"path":"/youtube/v3/subscriptions","method":"POST","params":{},"headers":{},"body":"snippet","root":"https://www.googleapis.com"},"wc":"auto"}}
```

So, I would like to know what's happening on that POST request and what's the solution to this.

I can post the full OAuth file, but it's just as in the example, plus that addSubscription method at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it working, the problem was on the POST request. Here is the full method working:

```
// Subscribes the authorized user to the channel specified
function addSubscription(channelSub) {
    var resource = {
        part: 'id,snippet',
        snippet: {
            resourceId: {
                kind: 'youtube#channel',
                channelId: channelSub
            }
        }
    };

    var request = gapi.client.youtube.subscriptions.insert(resource);
    request.execute(function (response) {
        var result = response.result;
        if (result) {
            // alert("Subscription completed");
            }
        } else {
            // alert("Subscripion failed");
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

Also make sure to load Google Apps API (in fact without it the authorize/login button won't work) and jQuery.

Comment: I am getting this error: `{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "'snippet'",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "'snippet'",
        "domain": "youtube.part",
        "reason": "unknownPart",
        "location": "part",
        "locationType": "parameter"
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: Is there version for Youtube api V3?